# Jquery slideup working but not slide down

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I don't know what I've done wrong with the code :|

http://javaphils.org/navigation/pag/

Click on the navigations, it slides up but the slidedown doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the bug is here :

```
success: function()
{
     $('#reconds').slideUp(5000,SmartAjax.proceed);
},
done: function()
{
    $('#reconds').slideDown(5000);
}
```

The SmartAjax.proceed certainly show the  div that your are filling info. So the div is already shown when you try to do the slide down. 
Everything else seems fine.